# Turn off status bar when (fullscreen = false) - Air for Android, AS3

Tags: android, xml, actionscript-3, flash, air

Basically I'm wondering if there's a way to turn **off** the status bar but **not** have fullscreen set to true.

Having fullscreen set to true does infact hide the status bar, **but** it also disables the screen from panning up when the soft keyboard pops up, therefore, hiding certain input text fields.

(This is a known, but not widely known, bug with air for android)

The only way the panning of text fields works seems to be when fullscreen is set to false, which brings me back to the beginning of this question.

Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Im using Flash CC 2014, AS3, Air 14.0 for Android

Comment: What is your `resizeForSoftKeyboard` in your main.mxml and `<softKeyboardBehavior>` in your app.xml set too?

Comment: My `app.xml` doesn't seem to have it declared anywhere, whether or not fullscreen mode is true or false, so it must be somewhere behind the scenes.

And the only.mxml file  I could find is `ApplicationUpdaterDialogs.mxml` located at 
`Applications/AdobeFlashCC2014/AIR13.0/frameworks/projects/air/ApplicationUpdater`

which has no `<softKeyboardBehaviour>` declared anywhere within it